# Find $x$ if $\frac {1} {x} + \frac {1} {y+z} = \frac {1} {2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

I found this question from past year's maths competition in my country. I've tried any possible way to find it, but it is just way too hard.

> Find $x$ if \begin{align}\frac {1} {x} + \frac {1} {y+z} &= \frac {1} {2}\\ \frac {1} {y} + \frac {1} {x+z} &= \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac {1} {z} + \frac {1} {x+y} &= \frac {1} {4}\end{align}
>
> $(A)\;\frac 32$
>
> $(B)\;\frac {17}{10}$
>
> $(C)\;\frac {19}{10}$
>
> $(D)\;\frac {21}{10}$
>
> $(E)\;\frac {23}{10}$

EDIT: I'm very sorry guys, it should be $\frac {1} {x+y}$ not $xy$, I'm sorry for the typos (idk what is wrong with me)

Comment: Hint: start with the last formula $$\frac {1} {x} +\frac {1} {y} + \frac {1} {z} + \frac {1} {xy}  + \frac {1} {yz} + \frac {1} {xz}= \frac {13}{12}$$ and multiply both sides by $xyz.$

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: are $x,y,z$ real numbers?

Comment: do you want to find special method to find x?or just find x? it is easy to find one value from first equation put another by this way find others

Comment: you mean eliminate the variable $x$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,yes

Comment: I tried using the standard methods below and didn't get the answer, but left it there to show the techniques and hopefully someone can spot the error

Comment: "solving your question" does not require "solving the system of equations" you have just to study the $5$ cases one by one (maybe not elegant but this is the shortest way) take $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and replace in the equations if you can find $y$ and $z$ then it's the good answer if there is a contradiction then go to the second option $\cdots$

Comment: apparently this was all an exercise in futility, as the question was typed in wrong.

Comment: @Elaqqad I disagree.  Answering the question on the test can be done by going through the cases.  However, the cases are an artifact of the way the test is designed, and no adequate solution worthy of being posted on math.SE will rely on case analysis unless there is a rationale for the cases beyond "the test had these as the possible answers." This is about problem solving, not test taking strategies.

Comment: @wuiyang And your thoughts on this are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac {1} {x} + \frac {1} {y+z} &= \frac {1} {2}\\ \frac {1} {y} + \frac {1} {x+z} &= \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac {1} {z} + \frac {1} {x+y} &= \frac {1} {4}
\end{align}

Is equivalent to the system
\begin{align}
xy+xz&=2(x+y+z)
\\
xy+yz&=3(x+y+z)
\\
xz+yz&=4(x+y+z),
\end{align}
Solving this system as a linear system of
equations in terms of $xy,xz$ and $yz$ and $x+y+z$,
we arrive at

\begin{align}
xy&=\tfrac12 (x+y+z), \quad(1)
\\
yz&=\tfrac52 (x+y+z),
\\
xz&=\tfrac32 (x+y+z).
\end{align}

Dividing these equations pairwise, we get
\begin{align}
z&=5x
\\
y&=\tfrac53 x,
\end{align}

combining with (1) we have

\begin{align}
\tfrac{5}{3}x^2-\tfrac{23}{6}x&=0
\end{align}
and since $x\ne0$, the answer is $x=\tfrac{23}{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

NOte: edit #1, equations changed when typo was noticed
NOTE!!!  This is not a complete solution, and there is likely something wrong with it.  I'm posting it for 2 reasons:  1: To show the type of logic one would use, and 2: To see if anyone can spot the mistake so it can be fixed.  (and 3, I spent so much time on it I don't want to delete it!)

Now:

Multiply through each equation by $xyz$ to get rid of the factions, and turn it into 3 equations in 3 unknowns:
$$yz+x=\frac 1 2 xyz $$
$$xz +y=\frac 1 3 xyz $$
$$xy+z=\frac 1 4 xyz $$

Let's go backwards and use the third equation to solve for z:  Subtract z from both sides and factor out the z, and you get $$xy=z(\frac 1 4 xy -1)$$, to clear the fractions I'm going to multiply through by 4 for convenious,  giving $$4xy=z(xy-4)$$,  thus $$z=\frac {4xy} {xy-4}$$  Now we plug that into our first two equations for $z$, giving us 
$$y(\frac {4xy} {xy-4})+x=\frac 1 2 xy(\frac {4xy} {xy-4}) $$ and
$$x(\frac {4xy} {xy-4})+y=\frac 1 3 xy(\frac {4xy} {xy-4}) $$

Now, we're going to solve the second equation for $y$.  Again, it's much easier to get rid of the fractions first, so I'm going to multiply the whole equation by $3(xy-4)$ to get $$12x^2y+3xy^2-12y^2=4x^2y^2$$ Every term has a $y$ and $y\ne 0$, so cancelling, we get $$12x^2+3xy-12y=4x^2y$$
Move the two terms with $y$ to the right hand side and factor out the $y$, and we get $$12x^2=y(4x^2+12-3x)$$, hence
$$y=\frac {12x^2} {4x^2 +12 -3x}$$

Now I need to plug that into our first equation, but before I do that, I'm going to clear out the denominators in the first equations, so I multiply through by $2(xy-4)$ to give us $$8x^2y^2+2x(xy-4)=xy$$ 
Again at this step I can divide through by an $x$, giving us 
$$8xy^2+2xy-8=y$$

Now, we plug in what we have $y$ for in terms of x, giving us $$8x(\frac {12x^2} {4x^2 +12 -3x})^2+2x(\frac {12x^2} {4x^2 +12 -3x})-8=\frac {12x^2} {4x^2 +12 -3x}$$

Continuing our theme of not dealing with fractions, we're going to multipy through by $(4x^2-12x-3)^2$ to get

$$8x(12x^2)^2+24x^3(4x^2-12x-3)-8(4x^2-12x-3)^2=12x^2(4x^2-12x-3) $$

Multiply this out and we have $$1152x^5+96x^5-288x^4-72x^3-128x^4+768x^3-960x^2-576x-72=48x^4-144x^3-36x^2$$  Moving everything to the left hand side and combining powers of $x$, we have $$1248x^5-464x^4+840x^3-924x^2-582x-72=0$$ 
The only simplification that can be done here is dividing by 2, which still gives us a quintic,  which has no easy way to solve.  Wolframalpha shows is now showing 3 real solutions, none of which match

Comment: I'm sure there is a mistake somewhere in your calculation.  There are five possible real solutions to this system of equations (I have checked with Mathematica).  However, none of the real solutions are nice.  If $a:=\frac{1}{x}$, then $114a^5-72a^4-288a^3+156a^2+119a-60=0$.

Comment: my question had typo, should be $\frac {1} {x+y}$ etc, not $xy$..

Comment: II changed the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=1/p$, $y=1/q$, and $z=1/r$.  The three equations become

$$\begin{align}
{1\over2}&=p+{qr\over q+r}={s\over q+r}\\
{1\over3}&=q+{rp\over r+p}={s\over r+p}\\
{1\over4}&=r+{pq\over p+q}={s\over p+q}\\
\end{align}$$

where

$$s=pq+qr+rp$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}
2s&=q+r\\
3s&=r+p\\
4s&=p+q\\
\end{align}$$

From this it follows that

$$(q+r)+(p+q)=2(r+p)\implies2q=r+p=3s\implies q={3\over2}s$$
and the others follow:

$$r=2s-q={1\over2}s\quad\text{and}\quad p=4s-q={5\over2}s$$

But now we have

$$s=pq+qr+rp={15\over4}s^2+{3\over4}s^2+{5\over4}s^2={23\over4}s^2$$

hence $s=4/23$, so $p=10/23$, and thus $x=23/10$.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying (2) by $x$ $(x \ne 0)$ we obtain
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{xy}$$
with (3) we obtain $$y=\frac{12(x^2-1)}{4x^2-3x}$$ (I)
from (1) and (3) we get 
$$\frac{x^2y}{3}-x^2+1=\frac{xy}{4}$$
plugging (I) in this equation  and simplifying we get 
$$-60 x^5+119 x^4+156 x^3-288 x^2-72 x+144=0$$
with five real solutions, no of them from (A) to (E)
the system after the correction has the solution $$x=\frac{23}{10}$$

Comment: my question had typo, should be $\frac {1} {x+y}$ etc, not $xy$.. sorry

Comment: hm it was also my time when I have solved your problem with the typo

Comment: and now i'm waiting for the downvoters of me

Answer (score 1):

Choosing
$p = \frac{1}{x} $
$q = \frac{1}{y}  $
$r = \frac{1}{z} $

will certainly help writing the equations more neatly, I guess.
Then your equations can be written as:

$$2p + 2qr = 1 \\ 3q + 3pr = 1 \\ 4r + 4pq = 1$$

using first two equations you get:

$$ 2p + 2qr = 3q + 3pr \\ \implies r = \frac{3q - 2p}{3p - 2q}$$

Substitute in equations and solve as solved by Alan above.